# How to check if webview failed to load page (android)?

Tags: android

I have a webview in my app, however sometimes due to connectivity the webview fails to load and I get the default webpage unavailable page. I want to show an alertdialog if the webview failed to load. Is there anyway I can check (maybe in the shouldOverridePageLoad function) that a webview loaded successfully? Thanks again

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use a WebClient on your web view as follow :

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

@Override public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request,
      WebResourceError error) {
    super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
    // Do something
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks man. I must've overlooked this method in the webview client. I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: and "onReceivedSslError"

Comment: You should take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33419123/149008 since onReceivedError is deprecated in API23

Comment: This answer needs modification since the new onReceivedError (since SDK 23) states that "the new version will be called for any resource (iframe, image, etc), not just for the main page. Thus, it is recommended to perform minimum required work in this callback."

Comment: That's not the right answer, since onRecievedError may happen also on an image which is part of this page. Meaning, it will call this method and you will indicate the failure although only one of the resources cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 20):

Extending on Damien's answer on using `WebViewClient`, there are four listeners available on `WebViewClient` to check for the success and failure of loading web pages.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpError(
            WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
                                   SslError error) {
    }
});
```

There is also:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
   }
});
```

which is deprecated in favor of its overload mentioned in the above code.