# onReceivedHttpError : support for android version < 23

Tags: android

I am working on a solution where I am loading a url. I need to get Http Error so that I can reload the url to create a new session.

```
@Override
   public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
            super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unexpected error occurred.Reload page again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(errorResponse.getStatusCode() == 401){
                customWebView.loadUrl(url);
            }
        }
```

But the problem with above code is that it work from Marshmallow. Can any one suggest me a solution where I can get error below android version < 23?

Answer (score 2):

[**`onReceivedHttpError`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)

```
void onReceivedHttpError (WebView view, 
                WebResourceRequest request, 
                WebResourceResponse errorResponse)
```

Notify the host application that an HTTP error has been received from the server while loading a resource.

> Can any one suggest me a solution where I can get error below android
>   version < 23

**`onReceivedHttpError`** Added in **`API level 23`**. So it will not work below 23.

Try with

```
.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {

        /*if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<23)
         {
            // You work
         }*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpError(
                WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {

        /*if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
            {
                 // Your Work
            }*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
                                       SslError error) {
        }
    });
```

**FYI**

[**`onReceivedError`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> This method was deprecated in API level 23. Use
>   onReceivedError(WebView, WebResourceRequest, WebResourceError)
>   instead.

Comment: So is there any alternative solution for the problem?

Comment: @ABHI Kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769505/webviewclient-onreceivederror-deprecated-new-version-does-not-detect-all-errors

Comment: @Amiya I had already seen that post. I just need a solution to implement for android version < 23

Comment: @ABHI Any feedback?

Comment: i tried few more things but couldn't find any substantial solution. So now I am putting some condition over the override method ShouldIntercept to fulfill my condition.