# Message extension of teams not working in Mobile App where message extension developed using SPFx

Tags: microsoft-teams, spfx

We have developed SPFx web part and using that in the Teams message extension task module we are using for that type as action.In desk top app we are able to open the task module from Teams app and able to perform the tasks. but its not working in the mobile app its getting the error "failed to load webview please check if the specified app is available  teams"

Manifest for the SPFx

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement and share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end.

Comment: Our Requirement is to create a Task module same as praise app and we will have different options to praise the persons so we have used the SPFx webpart and make it as Msg extension in the teams that is not opening in the teams  app Mobile app

Comment: You should take a look at this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016544/how-to-check-if-webview-failed-to-load-page-android

Comment: in SPFx we are not having any webview but we tried to add getting error after adding this also

Comment: have you ever found a solution? We're facing similar issue with SPFX in compose extension (nothing is loading)